# RabbitMQ queue order management

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm currently implementing rabbitMQ for a tracking system with multiple front producers writing on the same queue.

Basically i have two types of messages that are sent in the queue, as the tracking workflow has two steps : impression/click => lead/sale. 
It is very simple : The user clicks a banner, then performs an action on the website that he was redirected to. This action can take a few seconds to a few days to be done.
I need to consume the lead or sale AFTER the according impresison or click.

The problem is that i need to consume messages in a chronological order. While everything should be good if all producers send messages in the queue at the same speed (ie, the messages should order properly in a FIFO way) i will have issues when one of the producer writes (for some reason) slower in the queue.

For example, if my lead action occurs one second after the click action, and the click producers stalls for a couple seconds, i'll consume the lead before the click and my tracking system won't work.

I'd like to know how to set an order for a queue according to a header that's attached to the message.
All my servers are synchronized and their clocks have <1ns difference, so i'd like to order my queue according to this information, but i can't find anywhere in the doc a way to setup the queue order or consumption order.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AMQP queues  are FIFO queue. Under high numbers simultaneous message been published there might be some ambiguity which message come first, so you may expect that message `one` and message `two` might not be in same order in queue as they happened in real world. It's a price you have pay for HA and speed. If you want to know more about it you can ask a question on IRC rabbitmq channel.

Comment: Actually the problem doesnt lie with rabbitmq and "standard fifo", it's more that i try to compensate for potential hardware malfunctions through software ( ie : asking rabbitmq to reorder message in not FIFO way if one of my producers lags and takes too long to publish for some unknown reason).
Basically a terrible design practise that i should get rid of :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the queue means the queue, i.e. first in - first out. Mabe you can sort them during the consumption? I mean you take, for example, 10 messages from the queue, parse them, and put them to your own queue or list in the proper order.

Comment: Actually, i might have milions of message in the queue at one time, i can't have each consumer browse through all of those to find the most recent one .
I could on the other hand buy/install/configure a loadbalancer to ensure that successive actions within a "session" are handled by the same producing server. Right now i'm using DNS roundrobin for my front serveurs, which is cheap and easy.